# Show that 1-chains are 1-cycles but not 1-boundaries.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

$\textbf{The question is as follows:}$

> > In the torus $\mathbb{T}^d = S^1 \times \ldots \times  S^1$ consider the 1-chains $c_1, \ldots , c_d : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{T}^d$ defined by:
> >     $$c_j(t) \equiv (1, . . . , e^{2\pi it}, . . . , 1) ~~~~~~~~~~ (j = 1, . . . , d).$$
> >     Show that:
> >
> > (a) $~~$ The $c_j$ ’s are 1-cycles: $\partial c_j = 0$;
> >
> > (b) $~~$ The $c_j$’s are not 1-boundaries;
> >
> > (c) $~~$ The classes $\{[c_1], . . . , [c_d] \} \subset H_1(\mathbb{T}^d,R)$ form a linearly independent set.

$\textbf{some definition:}$

A 1-chain $c_j$ of $\mathbb{T}^d$ is called 1-cycle of $\mathbb{T}^d$ if $\partial_1 c_j = 0$. The 1-chain $c_j$ is said to be a 1-boundary of $\mathbb{T}^d$ if there exists a 2-chain $S$ of $\mathbb{T}^d$ such that $\partial_2 S = c_j$.

> > $\textbf{Hint:}$
> >
> > Use Stokes formula.

I do not know how to apply Stokes formula to this question.

Can someone let me know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: The map $\partial_1$ has nothing to do with a derivative. I would advice to read any book about algebraic topology, for example here : http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Many thanks! Can you please let me know how to apply that?

Comment: This is the subject of a full course so I'm not sure I'll be able to do a good job. I would say it is a direct consequence of the Kunneth formula but there are probably simpler way. I'm sure someone else will be able to give simpler proof for 2) and 3).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Many thanks! Can we show it by using Stokes formula?

Comment: Yes of course ! If $c = \partial S$ then for any closed form $\omega$ (that is, $d \omega = 0$) then we have $\int_c \omega =  \int_S d \omega = 0$. So you need to find a closed 1 form with $\int_c \omega \neq 0$. On $S^1$ such a form is $dz/z$, and you can easily adapt for your case.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Many thanks! Sorry, can you please explain it more? Can you please give me a full answer for all parts of the question? Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an expanded version of what I wrote in comments.

1) For a path $c : [0,1] \to X$, we say that $\partial c = 0$ if $c(0) = c(1)$, we call such a path closed, it is clear that your path is closed.

2) Let $\omega_i = d\theta_i$ where $\theta_i$ is the $i$-th angular coordinate. Then, $d \omega_i = 0$ but $\int_{c_i}\omega_i = 2\pi$ by an easy calculation. On the other hand, if $c_i$ was a boundary, say $c_i = \partial S_i$ then we should have $\int_{c_i}\omega_i = \int_{S_i} d\omega_i = 0$ which is not the case. This shows that $c_i$ is not a boundary.

3) Consider the linear form $\phi_i := \int_{c_i} - : H^1(X, \Bbb R) \to \Bbb R, \alpha \to \int_{c_i} \alpha$. By construction we have $\phi_i(\omega_j) = \delta_{ij}$, in particular $\omega_j$ are linearly independant cohomology classes.

4) A good reference should be the beginning of the book by Bott and Tu, *Differential forms in algebraic topology*. Alternatively, you could try *From Calculus to Cohomology* by Madsen.

Comment: Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer! I will try the book by Bott and Tu, Differential forms in algebraic topology. Thanks again!

Comment: Dear @user513784 I am glad I could help ! Good luck !